# Angular custom directive to update component

Tags: angularjs

I need to develop a custom directive to update an html multiselect component with the selections from another html multiselect component. Any hint on how to achieve it?

Comment: Why do you need a directive for that? Sounds like simple everyday case

Comment: I have to use a directive for design requirements. Any hint?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? It is much better to come to StackOverflow with "here is what I tried, why it is broken and what I want it to do" than "I need to do this, please do it for me".

Comment: OK, post your code, what have you tried so far and what you need to achieve, otherwise the question is too broad

Comment: I managed to generate the ui components with the directives, my only doubt is how to pass the list of selections from the first htmlmultiselect to the second  one. In order to fill the second with the selections from the first one.

Comment: You can pass data between directives by 'requiring' one inside the other but these directives don't really qualify for that kind of structure. You could always just put the list on $rootScope and retrieve it from the other directive. Are the two directives on the same html page or are they linked at a different time from each other?

Comment: Sorry, I did a type error. I have only one directive to handle the two html multiselect components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what your looking for, but you could try something like this:

```
myApp.directive("customDirective", function () {
  return {
    replace : true,
    template : '<div><select multiple="" ng-model="valuesA" ng-options="item.text for item in listA"></select>' +
               '<select multiple="" ng-model="valuesB" ng-options="item.text for item in valuesA"></select></div>',

    controller : function ($scope) {
      $scope.valuesA = [];
      $scope.valuesB = [];

      $scope.listA = [
        {text : "item 1", value: 1},
        {text : "item 2", value: 2},
        {text : "item 3", value: 3},
        {text : "item 4", value: 4}
      ];
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In my case the situation is more difficult but you provided me a great hint.